# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on HP 23-h017c all-in-one

Tags: failover

I went through the whole process of installing it, them after i was told to remove to boot device an restart i get the "No bootable device found" error message. And also in my bios i don't see the option to "Select an UEFI file as trusted for executing" Please help me, I'm slightly new with ubuntu.

Comment: If your boot device is set properly in BIOS, then you need to go through [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) process.

Comment: How to i do that? i did the boot repair while in the try ubuntu mode on the hp. But after i installed it once again i still get no boot disk detected. But when i go to reinstall it does show that ubuntu was already installed on the HDD